# How to write unit test with Higher Order Function with Jest in React JS

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, higher-order-functions

Hello i'm new to React and i'm trying to write a unit test on a Higher Order Functions with Jest and i don't know how to do it please can someone help me ? This is the code of my  HIGHER ORDER FUNCTION  below  :

```
const updateSearchTopStoriesState = (hits, page) => (prevState) => {
    const { searchKey, results } = prevState


    const oldHits = results && results[searchKey]
        ? results[searchKey].hits
        : []


    const updatedHits = [
        ...oldHits,
        ...hits
    ]
    // returning our previous state 
    return {
        results: {
            ...results,
            [searchKey]: { hits: updatedHits, page }
        },
        isLoading: false
    }
}

export default updateSearchTopStoriesState
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: Looks like incomplete code. Please, if possible, provide a [Minimal, Reproducible, and Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces an issue you are having, and share *specifically* what you've tried and what isn't working.

Comment: HI i complete the code, I want to test if  the first class  function receive arguments present in his signature in his definition ? 
and also for for the return function

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing *WHAT* you are trying to test, or *WHAT* the shape of any of the parameters are, this is near impossible to answer accurately. Here are a couple of unit tests I would write:

```
describe("updateSearchTopStoriesState", () => {
  it("should return a function", () => {
    expect(typeof updateSearchTopStoriesState()).toBe("function");
  });

  it("should return default return value", () => {
    const { results, isLoading } = updateSearchTopStoriesState()({
      searchKey: "test"
    });

    expect(results).toEqual({ test: { hits: [] } });
    expect(isLoading).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

[image: Edit spring-violet-nizth]

In the sandbox I've started a third test that currently fails (admittedly likely due to my lack of context on the parameters, but should be passing based upon an internal implementation comment you left in the function code).

This should assist you in starting a unit test file for this function, but please comment if anything is unclear or this isn't quite what you are asking about.

Comment: Thank for the answer, so let me explain you the context
My app fetch data from a remote Api based on the a search term entered by user ,
So this function 'updateSearchTopStories '  receive in parameters the most recently result data fetch from the API and  must return a function wich receive in his argument the previousState value , so that i could merge the previous value in the state with the recent data fetch from API 
So i want to test if the function  receive parameters first ,  and  return another function with parameters (which is the previous state ). Thanks